# PHP PDO bindValue() fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindvalue

I'm new to PHP's PDO and got a little problem with a function of my database class:

```
function set($query, $args = array())   {
try {
    $query = $this->rs->prepare($query);

    $x = 1;
    foreach($args as $arg)  {
        $query -> bindValue($x, $arg);
        $x++;
    }

    $query->execute($args);
}
catch(PDOException $e)  {
    print_r($e);
}
}
```

It's supposed to automatically bind the "?" in the query to their value in the array `$args`.

Example:

```
$db -> set("INSERT INTO messages(date,regard,sender,to,msg) VALUES('?','?','?','?','?')", array(
    "bla",
    "bla2",
    "bla3",
    "bla4",
    "bla4"
));
```

But it doesn't work. In the database, all cols contains those stupid question marks. Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried it with ? without quotation marks?

Comment: Sidenote: `to` is a reserved word and needs to be wrapped in backticks. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html in your `(date,regard,sender,to,msg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quoted your question marks, so the database sees literal strings containing just a single `?`, instead of the placeholder marker (question mark). Simply use the question mark without quoting it: the system automatically uses the correct syntax for the relevant data types.

Comment: Ah, I'll try this. If this really works I did a very stupid mistake... Again...

Edit: It really works! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the quotation marks from your query:

```
$db -> set("INSERT INTO messages(date,regard,sender,to,msg) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", array(
    "bla",
    "bla2",
    "bla3",
    "bla4",
    "bla4"
));
```

If you are only input strings, then you can force this with a third parameter in `bind_value` `PDO::PARAM_STR`

```
$query -> bindValue($x, $arg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like with out quotes `'?'` i.e it should be `?`

```
$db -> set("INSERT INTO messages(date,regard,sender,to,msg) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", array(
"bla",
"bla2",
"bla3",
"bla4",
"bla4"
));
```